# Need to calculate and store age from birth to death date

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a sql table of people data named `caduti` with date column `data_nasc`(date of birth) and `data_dec`(date of death).
I need to calculate age (in years) at death and set this value in `eta` column.
I have tried some query, like this one:

```
UPDATE caduti
SET caduti.eta =     
    DATEDIFF(YY, caduti.data_nasc, caduti.data_dec) - 
    CEILING
     (0.5 * SIGN (
        (MONTH(caduti.data_nasc) - MONTH(caduti.data_dec)) * 50
         + DAY(caduti.data_nasc) - DAY(caduti.data_dec)
        )
      )
```

but it doesn't work. My need is not only t calculate the ages but also to store them in table column. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
update 
caduti
set caduti.eta = (year(data_dec) - year(data_nasc) - (date_format(data_dec, '%m%d') < date_format(data_nasc, '%m%d')));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This solution is very simple and efficient and solve my problem.